# c++ unique pointer: memory leak

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I am little confused about release method of unique pointer. Here is my sample program.

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test(){std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl;}
    ~Test(){std::cout << "dtor" << std::endl;}
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Test> ptr(new Test());
    ptr.release(); // memory leak
    //ptr.reset(); // this is ok but not necessary
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
ctor
```

Since it is not printing `dtor` i am assuming it is not calling destructor of `Test` which will lead to memory leak. **Is it**?

Comment: FWIW, since you're using `unique_ptr`, in your example code, the destructor will be called without doing anything at all, when `main()` returns - no need for `reset`,`release` or `delete` (which won't compile with a `unique_ptr`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The word `release` means "release **ownership** to the caller". So no, the destructor isn't called by it.

If you want to call the destructor *explicitly* then you have to either `delete` the `release`d pointer manually, or just call `reset`, which is the preferred way to do it.
If you don't need to do this explicitly then you can just leave it and it'll get taken care of automatically.

Comment: so there will be memory leak if i call release as in above example ?

Comment: @dream_machine: Yeah.

Comment: dream_machine is probably thinking of COM, where `release()` means to decrement the reference count and potentially destroy the object.

Comment: @dream_machine: Note that memory leaks and destructor calls are two different things. `delete` calls the destructor **and** releases the memory. But it's possible to do one but not the other. `release` does neither.

Comment: actually i got confused with release word which is commonly use to free resources :)

Comment: @dream_machine: Haha yeah that's a really good point, it seems so obvious now that you mention it but I hadn't thought of that!

Comment: Don't forget unique_ptr is a smart pointer. It will also be destructed and the memory freed when it goes out of scope if you don't do anything .